Error loading script: Ensure you are running Metro or that your index.android.bundle package is bundled
I started a new job at a consulting company, and on my first day, the senior team members left. Now, I need to start programming, but I'm encountering an error when trying to emulate using Android Studio. I've tried various troubleshooting steps, but whenever I run npm start, the issue persists.
I've attempted to clear the React Native cache, desintall and reinstall the Node Modules, checked the environment variables, uninstalled and reinstalled Metro, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

Hello! Please read this guide on creating a minimal, reproducible example and edit your post accordingly so we can better understand your error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
